# Error 404 Not Found Loading Bootstrap Glyphicons with Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, maven, spring-mvc

I'm building a maven web application using Spring 3.0.5 MVC,  AngularJS 1.5 and Boostrap 3.3.6.

All front-end resources are under `webapp/resources/[js,css,fonts]`.

I've add `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` to my spring configuration file.

My issue is that i'm not able to get **glyphicons-halflings-regular.xxx** files. I got a **404 not found** error. (exemple with http://localhost:8080/my-app/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff)

I run my app with maven jetty plugin.

any hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check that your font files are being copied to the target folder you expect them to be copied to. In your case, you should end up with the *.woff files under ~target/my-app/resources/fonts.

If the files are not in the correct/expected target location, check that you have correctly defined the resources element in your pom, and you're including the *.woff files.

Based on what you've said, I would expect your files to be placed into ~/target/my-app/[js,css,fonts] rather than ~/target/my-app/resources/[js,css,fonts].  If you see them there, then you can either remove the /resources portion of the links, or move the resources under /src/main/resources/resources.

If there are no *.woff files in the target folder at all, check the `<resource>` element of your pom and make sure you're including all the file types you want. If you need more control, take a look at the copy-resources goal of the maven-resources-plugin here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

**Edit**

I just noticed that you put your resources under /src/main/webapp/resources. Since this isn't the standard resource source folder, you can either move the resources into /src/main/resources or add the directory /src/main/webapp/resources to your resource list in the pom.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelPeacock, you were right *.woff files were not copied in the target folder. I've added this the code below and now files are added to resources. **But I still have the probleme of 404 not found** `<resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>/src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.eot</include>
              <include>**/*.svg</include>
              <include>**/*.ttf</include>
              <include>**/*.woff</include>
              <include>**/*.woff2</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
  </resources>`